# Laravel cannot sending email

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I use passoword reset scripts(default in Laravel). My SMTP configuration is in .env. When I go to *URL/password/reset* - it's show form and I type a email. Then when submit the form my browser show *password/email* with message "**Service is temporarily unavailable**". How I fix it?

Thanks in advance!
Edit: Code:

```
return [

    'driver' => 'smtp', //EDITED

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'admin@it.bgschool.bg'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Мартин Якимов'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('EMAIL'),

    'password' => env('PASSWORD'),


    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Now the error is

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Comment: Have you modified it? Have you tested using mailtrap? Show some code...

Comment: With mailtrap it's work perfectly but now it's with Webmail.

Comment: Which code I show?

Comment: I can only assume without seeing.. Your SMTP information is incorrect. Have you changed the mail_from_address?

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=bgschool.icnhost.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

This information is form my hosting provider.

Comment: You need to assign an email address and password to the .env too

Comment: Yes, I resplace it with 'email' and 'password'

Comment: 465 the correct outgoing mailing port yes?

Comment: Yes, this is from their website.

Comment: With mailtrap on localhost is working. Now on the hosting - NOT. Same error?

Comment: Have you changed the mail_from_address within config/ ?

Comment: I noticed on mine you need to change mail_from_address / name within config/mail.php also.

Comment: Yes, I changed.

Comment: and... now that you have changed it, is it working?

Comment: Not work again.

Comment: show us config/mail.php

Comment: I updated main post :). See it there.

Comment: Try adding encryption method.
Also don't forget to change port after changing encryption method.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
```

to

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
```

and on your mail.php you are using:

```
'username' => env('EMAIL'),
'password' => env('PASSWORD'),
```

while on your .env you are using:

```
MAIL_USERNAME=email 
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
```

You have to change in one of them.

Comment: Yes, I was changed email and password. I will try your answer.

Comment: Now the error is 
> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Comment: How I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The password in .env is the same as config/app.php